# Embed image in XML docs

Tags: f#

The MSDN page about XML documentation shows that you can write simple things like:

```
/// <summary>Builds a new string whose characters are the results of applying the function <c>mapping</c>
/// to each of the characters of the input string and concatenating the resulting
/// strings.</summary>
/// <param name="mapping">The function to produce a string from each character of the input string.</param>
///<param name="str">The input string.</param>
///<returns>The concatenated string.</returns>
///<exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">Thrown when the input string is null.</exception>
val collect : (char -> string) -> string -> string
```

But can you embed images in your XML documentation?

Answer (score 3):

You can include `<img ... />` and other HTML tags in the XML documentation. I just tried this and Visual Studio simply skips over the image (so you will not see it in the IntelliSense) but the `fshtmldoc` tool in F# Power Pack simply copies the HTML tags to the output HTML document including images.

```
/// <summary>Hi <img src="http://tomasp.net/img/fpman.jpg" /> there!</summary>
type IMultiKey = 
  // (...)
```

Gives me the following generated documentation:

[image]

I think the C# compiler does some additional validation of the XML tags, but I do not think this is done in the F# compiler. As an aside, I find writing the XML documents a annoyingly long, so I was playing with using [F# Formatting](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting) to write them in Markdown instead (but I do not have anything ready yet).